# Can changes to domain object fields cause a grails domain to be considered modified/ dirty?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given a domain class:

```
class Book {
    def title
    Author author
}

class Author {
   def name
}
```

Given a book instance:

```
Author author = new Author(name: 'joe')
author.save()
Book book = new Book(author:author, title: 'groovy book')
book.save()
```

If I change the name of the author:

```
author.name = 'john'
```

Is the book considered dirty? or modified?

Comment: The `title` and `name` properties should be assigned a `String` type, rather than `def` if you want them to be persisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `book` is not considered `dirty` in this case since the `book` is already saved. Only the `author` is considered `dirty`. Given that no properties of the `book` have changed and only a property of the `author` has.

Comment: This is true, and you can use some GORM helper methods to see that (`println author.isDirty()`, `println book.isDirty()`, `println author.getDirtyPropertyNames()`, `println book.getDirtyPropertyNames()`) but logically you could argue that if an instance's property is dirty, then it's dirty. If this used the traditional collection-based mapping approach where the book is persisted via `author.addToBooks(book)` then a change in a book instance would dirty the Author, and saving the Author would transitively validate and save the Book. But this isn't how it's working in the inverse case.